# Is it possible only to use second derivative and one pair of x,y values to find equation of a curve?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I recently encountered a question as follows:

> At every point (x, y) on a certain curve, we have $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=5$. When $x=2$, $y$ attains a minimum value of $10$. Find the equation of the curve.

Given this second-order differential equation, I thought of computing $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x+C$ as an antiderivative, then, similarly, find $y=\frac{5x^2}{2}+Cx+D$ where C and D are arbitrary constants. However, what matters me is that I cannot solve C and D provided that there's no information given for the first derivative.

Is it really possible I can find the equation of the curve with only two pieces of information given? If no, any alternatives for solving this question? Thanks!

Comment: The minimum tells you the derivative is 0 at 2 and the function has value 10 at 2.

Comment: You have two pieces of information:  the point $(2,10)$ and the word *minimum*

Comment: @DavidMitra you mean the absolute minimum of a function?

Comment: Seems to be phrased as an absolute, but with some assumptions on the domain, it would also be a local min.

Comment: Ohh I was clearly mistaken! Nevertheless, I initially thought the 'minimum' would be the numerical minimum (i.e. $x=2$ when $y \geqslant 10$)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $y'' = 5$.

Integrating, we get
$$
y' = 5 x + C.
$$

Integrating again, we get
$$
y = {5 \over 2} x^2 + C x + D.
$$

The minimum value of $y$ is obtained by finding the critical points of $y$.

Thus, we solve
$$
y' = 0 \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ 5 x + C = 0 \ \ x = -{C \over 5}
$$

(Since $y'' = 5 > 0$, the critical point yields a minimum value.)

The minimum value of $y$ is attained at $x = 2$ as $y_\min = 10$.

Substituting $x = 2$ in the critical point result
$$
x = -{C \over 5},
$$
we get $C = -5 x = -5 (2) = -10$.

Thus,
$$
y = {5 \over 2} \ x^2 - 10 x + D
$$

Given that $y(2) = 10$. Thus,
$$
10 = {5 \over 2} \ (2)^2 - 10 (2) + D 
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
10 = \left( {5 \over 2} \times 4 \right) - 20 + D = 10 - 20 + D
$$
or
$$
D = 20
$$

Hence, the unique solution of the differential equation is
$$
\boxed{y(x) = {5 \over 2} \ x^2 - 10 x + 20}
$$
[image: Graph]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

We have $y(x)=k(x-2)^2+10$.  From $y''(x)=5$ we know that $k=5/2$.